# Syntax to return an instance in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

can u please help me how to return an instance of a function which is inherited through interface in Objective-C Language?

```
@protocol prot1

{

public IDispManager getDispManager;

}
@end
@interface A: NSObject (prot1)

{

}
@end

@implementation A

{
   /**
     * Provides access to the disp manager.
     * @return Instance of the disp manager.
     */
   public IDispManager getDispManager;

   // how to return an instance of this method
}
 @end
```

Plssss help me out???????

Comment: May I suggest you to check your Objective-C syntax?

Comment: ya sure.. suggest me... i've my @protcol n @interface in header files n @implementation in source files.

Comment: parenthesis on method signatures are not valid objective-C. angle brackets in @implementation body are not valid objective-C. You can learn all of this in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: This is not Objective-C but Objective-Java.

Comment: This is tagged objective-C and the question mentions explicitely objective-C. Should the tag and the question be edited?

Comment: @mouviciel: Sorry for causing confusion, I was just joking. There is no language named "Objectve-Java". The posted code is just a convoluted mix of both of these laguages.

Comment: OK, I didn't catch the joke. There is a language called Objective-C++ and another called ruby-cocoa, so I wasn't surprised by a language called Objective-Java...

Comment: nw i've changed my code... since this is 1st time i'm coding in Objective-C, there seems to be some mistakes, so plz don joke upon it, U can always correct me... is the code proper... ???But more than anything i just want to knw how to return an instance of the the method. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class would have to hold an object of that class and provide a method to return it. Here's an example along the lines of what you wanted to write:

```
@protocol Proto
- (DisplayManager *)displayManager;
@end

@interface Foo : NSObject <Proto> {
    DisplayManager *displayManager;
}
- (DisplayManager *)displayManager;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (DisplayManager *)displayManager {
    return [[displayManager retain] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Though this probably won't make sense to you without understanding the language more fully.

Comment: Thnaks a lots... i've understood most of ur code... hey 1 more question... 5th line in ur code i.e [DisplayManager *displayManager;] , can u plz say me what does the line do?if i'm not wrong is it a object of class DisplayManager??? and @class is to be mentioned as @interface in Objective-C right? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: That line declares an instance variable of the class Foo that points to an object of class DisplayManager. It would have to be set in the class initializer or at some other point. And you're right, `@class` should have been `@interface`. Careless mistake on my part. Sorry about that.

Comment: ok .. 

(1)Can @protocol, @interface come in a single file.. i.e in .h file?? and @implementation in .m file... ??? is it a proper coding method??? 

(2)And also plz tel me can i package all my @protocol as a single package and access it in which ever @interface i need ??? I use to do it in Java but i don knw the procedure to package in Objective-C. or else should i cont by writing as i mentioned in 1st point..??

Comment: Yes, you can place class interfaces and protocols in the same header file. As for packaging, Objective-C does not have any such concept of "packages". Code is stored in files, not packages. You can put multiple headers into one file, or you can put them into individual files and have one "master" file that imports them all (which is how it's usually done). Generally it's best to try to group things logically.

Comment: Can u do me a favour ?? Can u send some links of example source code of Objective-C projects written for iPhone OS?Any open source based. I just want to get an idea hw a project is written and how the instances are being used...

Comment: @suse: That would be a good question to ask. This is a Q&A site — that's the whole point. Lots of users here to help. I'm not necessarily going to be on here checking this stuff every day.

Comment: ok ...
As U mentioned before tat Objective-C does not have any concept of "packages",then wat is *.framework in Targets folders in XCode.its symbol is like a package... i've a snapshot of it for more clearer understanding... but dont knw how to copy it in Stack overflow ....

Comment: @suse: Frameworks are an OS X way of grouping libraries and related files together. I guess you can view them as being like packages, but they exist at the filesystem level, not the language level. In order to do something like `import foo.bar.*`, you need to create a header that imports all the relevant files in the framework and import that. At any rate, I wouldn't create a framework unless you really have a large, coherent collection of classes and related resources. Because it's a PITA and you're usually better off just with loose source files in a version control repo.